# Is it okay to mock multiple objects in one class?

Tags: tdd, mocking

For developers with extensive experience using mocks, **is it okay to mock multiple objects in one class (ie satisfy multiple interfaces) or is this not recommended?**

I am wondering because mocks are stubs anyway, from a testing perspective, it doesn't seem to make a big difference if I consolidate mocks.

However, I do wonder if there are negative impacts from a maintenance/clarity POV.

Comment: [Mocks Aren't Stubs](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only think of a couple of situations where it might be a bad idea:

1. If your unit tests are part of the documentation (e.g. for a shared API) then you don't want to set a bad example. If you expect that real implementations would implement more than one interface then you can/should ignore this.
2. If your mock classes are anything more than simple stubs, then you risk making them unnecessarily complicated. Hopefully this falls under common sense!

With those exceptions, I don't see it being a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is perfectly fine.

One example I could think of is the MVP design pattern. If you pass model and view objects to the presenter with their interfaces, then you **have to** pass two mock objects in unit tests.

Comment: How is that example relevant? Yes, you would have to pass in View and Model references, but I don't see how that has any bearing on whether the objects are of 2 separate classes or of one class which implements both the View and Model interfaces...

Comment: @Baqueta The example shows that it is perfectly fine to pass more then one mocks to a class. That is the point of the question : *is it okay to mock multiple objects in one class (ie satisfy multiple interfaces) or is this not recommended?*

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. By "satisfy multiple interfaces" I think he means having a mock class like `class MockViewModel implements View, Model { /* ... */ }`